# Copy boot data from Ram to flash on a stm32board

Tags: flash, embedded, stm32, bootloader, stm32cubeide

I am trying to copy the contents stored in my RAM to flash during startup of my code, I want to know what steps are involved to achieve something like that ,I know we have to unlock the flash and erase the pages,but I want to know how the principle of how it works

I searcher about this everywhere but very limited information is available on this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, clarifying what you concretely want to know. You might want to add which resources you already used to find answers.

Comment: @0___________ Umm yeah I read that all backwards. Nevermind! Comment deleted

Answer (score 1):

> I searcher about this everywhere but very limited information is
> available on this

There is a lot of information (and I do believe that you put too much effort into your research) but the most important document is a ***Refernce Manual*** for your microcontroller. You can find it on the STM32 website. Example: [STM32F103](https://file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Downloads/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Basically, you need to (for STM32F405):

1. Unlock FLASH
   [image]
2. Erase sector where you want to place your date:
   [image]
3. Program the data:
   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much ,this reallly helped